# IF EXISTS statement alternative in HANA

Tags: hana

I want looked for "if exists", but HANA SQL was not understand for "if exists". whether I was created SQL-command wrong.

If 'Y' for the record exists in table from `ZZZ_Exercise_3`, else 'N' for the record not exists in table from `ZZZ_Exercise_3`. If old record for 'N' then this record delete should.

```
 CREATE COLUMN TABLE ers.ZZZ_EXERCISE_5(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY generated by default as IDENTITY,
    Orig_ID INT,
    COMPANY nvarchar(251),
    VALID char(1)
);

COMMIT;

IF EXISTS(
    INSERT INTO ZZZ_EXERCISE_5(Orig_ID, COMPANY, VALID)
    SELECT ID, COMPANY, 'Y' FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_3
)
ELSE(
    INSERT INTO ZZZ_EXERCISE_5(Orig_ID, COMPANY, VALID)
    SELECT ID, COMPANY, 'N' FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_3
)

COMMIT;

UPDATE ZZZ_EXERCISE_3
SET COMPANY = (SELECT COMPANY FROM ERS.ZZZ_EXERCISE_5)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT COMPANY FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_5 WHERE ZZZ_EXERCISE_5.VALID = 'N')

COMMIT;

DELETE FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_3
WHERE ERS.ZZZ_EXERCISE_5.VALID = 'N'

SELECT * FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT COMPANY FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_5 WHERE ZZZ_EXERCISE_5.ID = ZZZ_EXERCISE_3.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SQL dialect would accept your statement, but IF-THEN-ELSE is typically part of the procedural extension like PL/SQL, T-SQL or SQLScript in SAP HANA.

If you explain more about what you want to achieve (instead of just posting some non-standard syntax that does not work), there are likely options to do it in SAP HANA.

---

If 'Y' for the record exists in table from ZZZ_Exercise_3, else 'N' for the record not exists in table from ZZZ_Exercise_3. If old record for 'N' then this record delete should.

Based on the revised description, my understanding is that you want

1. For every record in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5`: 
   check if it exists in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_3` and if so, set the `VALID` field in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5` to `Y`.
   If the records exist in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_3` but not in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5`, insert that record into `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5`.
   If the records don't exist in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_3` but in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5`, set `VALID` to `N`.
2. After that, you want to delete all records from `ZZZ_EXERCISE_3` for which a matching record in `ZZZ_EXERCISE_5` has `VALID` = `N`

For step 1, you want to look into the

Step 2 is the easier one, so let's start with that:

```
   DELETE FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_3 
   WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID 
                FROM ZZZ_EXERCISE_5 
                WHERE VALID ='N');
```

Step 1 is a bit more complicated as it shall combine UPDATEs and INSERTS. For this, SAP HANA provides the `MERGE` command (also called `REPLACE`). [MERGE|REPLACE DOCU](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2cfbc5cf2bc14f028cfbe2a2bba60a50/2.0.00/en-US/20fc06a7751910149892c0d09be21a38.html)

With SAP HANA 2, there also a new command `MERGE INTO` that is closer to the commonly used `MERGE` command in other DBMS. [MERGE INTO DOCU](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2cfbc5cf2bc14f028cfbe2a2bba60a50/2.0.00/en-US/3226201f95764a57810dd256c9524d56.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will change my question for better understand and more details. Whether you better understand can.