# How to do an IF EXISTS in hana SQL query

Tags: sql, hana

I have this query code:

```
IF EXISTS  ( 

SELECT 

 *

 FROM sys.objects

 WHERE object_id =
 OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING]') 

 AND type in (N'U')

)

 DROP TABLE
 [dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING] 

GO 
 CREATE TABLE
```

I am trying to use this statement to query an SAP Hana Database. The beginning of the query `IF EXISTS` keeps throwing an error, I assume that this means that this keyword does not exist in Hana SQL syntax. Does anyone know how to do an `IF EXISTS` check in Hana, as I am unable to find any answer online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111389/sap-hana-sql-for-if-exists

Answer (score 4):

If EXISTS is a non-standard syntax that HANA doesn't support. 
As an alternative you can query the catalog and write a `IF...THEN` statement in SQLScript.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using IF EXISTS could be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = (
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING]')
        AND type IN (N'U'))
    THEN (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING]')
        AND type IN (N'U'))
    ELSE
        NULL
    END
)
AND type IN (N'U')
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQLScript does not have IF EXIST condition.**
But same logic can be achieved by creating a variable (flag) that is initialized by your first query.
You dont need to select all the columns. You can select as an example object_id.

```
flag = '';

SELECT object_id INTO flag FROM sys.objects
 WHERE object_id =
 OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING]') 
 AND type in (N'U');

IF flag != '' THEN
  DROP TABLE [dbo].[BAL_WMS_STAGING]
END IF;
```